# Is strsplit the fastest way to separate a string in R

Tags: r, performance, strsplit

I have a string, `"1500|3|10000|5"` and I wish to have a numeric vector like so:

`[1]  1500     3 10000     5`

strsplit is much faster than `str_extract_all`. Is strsplit the fastest way to do this?

```
library("tidyverse")
library("microbenchmark")

x <- "1500|3|10000|5"

# mean ~ 137 microseconds
microbenchmark(
  x |> 
    str_extract_all("\\d+") |> 
    unlist(use.names = FALSE) |> 
    as.double() 
)

# mean ~ 15 microseconds
microbenchmark(
  x |> 
    strsplit(split = "\\|") |> 
    unlist(use.names = FALSE) |> 
    as.double() 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringi` seems to be slightly faster, also pipe should be omitted for max speed.

```
library(stringr)
library(stringi)

set.seed(123)
x <- paste0(sample(100000), collapse = '|')

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  str_extract = x |> 
    str_extract_all("\\d+") |> 
    unlist(use.names = FALSE) |> 
    as.double() , 
  strsplit = x |> 
    strsplit(split = "\\|") |> 
    unlist(use.names = FALSE) |> 
    as.double() , 
  strsplit_fixed = x |> 
    strsplit(split = '|', fixed = TRUE) |> 
    unlist(use.names = FALSE) |> 
    as.numeric(),
  
  stringi = as.numeric(stri_split_fixed(x, '|')[[1]]),
  stringi2 = x |> 
    stri_split_fixed(pattern = '|') |> 
    unlist(use.names = FALSE) |> 
    as.numeric()
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#           expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
#    str_extract 27.5158 27.77085 28.63940 28.01650 28.32090  36.7092   100   c 
#       strsplit 50.6624 51.16750 52.11587 51.55955 51.98610  59.2446   100    d
# strsplit_fixed 18.9921 19.24650 20.95589 19.40140 19.68805 113.9647   100  b  
#        stringi 17.8246 18.13970 18.53155 18.31015 18.57825  26.4410   100 a   
#       stringi2 18.2519 18.64035 19.21868 18.78765 19.20105  27.1056   100 ab
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that this question is because you have a large pipe-delimited file and you need to turn it into a data frame.

If you've already read the file into a char vector `x`:

```r
x <- readLines("mydelimfile.txt")

# base R
df <- read.delim(text=x, sep="|", header=FALSE)

# with readr
df <- readr::read_delim(paste0(x, collapse="\n"), delim="|", col_names=FALSE)
```

But you can just convert the file directly into a df:

```r
df <- read.delim("mydelimfile.txt", sep="|")

df <- readr::read_delim("mydelimfile.txt", delim="|")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `fixed = TRUE` in `strsplit` provides better results. On a larger sample `str_extract_all` performs better than `strsplit` code in your post.

```
library(stringr)

set.seed(123)
x <- paste0(sample(100000), collapse = '|')

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
str_extract = x |> 
              str_extract_all("\\d+") |> 
              unlist(use.names = FALSE) |> 
              as.double() , 

strsplit = x |> 
           strsplit(split = "\\|") |> 
           unlist(use.names = FALSE) |> 
           as.double() , 

strsplit_fixed = x |> 
                 strsplit(split = '|', fixed = TRUE) |> 
                 unlist(use.names = FALSE) |> 
                 as.numeric() 
)

#Unit: milliseconds
#           expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval cld
#    str_extract 27.00734 28.68815 30.62537 29.62420  31.59296  55.36550   100  b 
#       strsplit 87.71705 91.47075 97.39022 94.99620 101.27776 123.17484   100   c
# strsplit_fixed 17.57684 20.08943 23.03720 21.59174  23.40159  49.83912   100 a
```